# Convert a GeoJSON file coming from Overpass in shapefile using ogr2ogr in command line

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, overpass-api

I need to convert a GeoJSON file coming from an Overpass query in a ESRI Shapefile using ogr2ogr in command line (I'm on Ubuntu 15.10 .. )

This is my query edited in Overpass Turbo

```
[out:json][timeout:250];
{{geocodeArea:Italia}}->.searchArea;
(
  node["amenity"="hospital"]["emergency"="yes"](area.searchArea);
);
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

and how is converted in Overpass XML (using Export functionality in Overpass Turbo .. )

```
<osm-script output="json" output-config="" timeout="250">
  <id-query into="searchArea" ref="3600365331" type="area"/>
  <union into="_">
    <query into="_" type="node">
      <has-kv k="amenity" modv="" v="hospital"/>
      <has-kv k="emergency" modv="" v="yes"/>
      <area-query from="searchArea" into="_" ref=""/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" limit="" mode="body" n="" order="id" s="" w=""/>
  <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" limit="" mode="skeleton" n="" order="quadtile" s="" w=""/>
</osm-script>
```

I put this in a file named `ps-Italy-from-OSM.txt` and then I'm download the data using this command:

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=<proxy>:port> --post-file=ps-Italy-from-OSM.txt http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter --output-document=ps-Italy-OSM.json
```

Al works fine but, when I try to convert the json data in an ESRI Shapefile using this ogr2ogr command from command line

```
ogr2ogr -nlt POINT -skipfailures ps-Italy-OSM-WGS84.shp ps-Italy-OSM.json OGRGeoJSON
```

I obtain this error ...

```
ERROR 4: Failed to read GeoJSON data
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `ps-Italy-OSM.json' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> NAS
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> LIBKML
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> Interlis 1
  -> Interlis 2
  -> GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> DODS
  -> ODBC
  -> WAsP
  -> PGeo
  -> MSSQLSpatial
  -> OGDI
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> MySQL
  -> PCIDSK
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> Geomedia
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> GME
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> PDF
  -> Walk
  -> CartoDB
  -> SXF
```

Answer (score 2):

Your result is JSON, not GeoJSON. That's why OGR cannot handle it.

Comment: As a workaround, try `out:xml`, which will deliver an .osm file that OGR can handle. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_Format_.28out.29 for allowed values.

Comment: I've tried but when I try to convert to ESRI shapefile using `ogr2ogr -nlt POINT -skipfailures ps-Italy-OSM-WGS84.shp ps-Italy-OSM.xml` I obtain the same error `Unable to open datasource ps-Italy-OSM.xml with the following drivers`. Do you've a sample?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this way ... I've changed my file named ps-Italy-from-OSM.txt as follow ...

```
<osm-script output="xml" output-config="" timeout="250">
  <id-query into="searchArea" ref="3600365331" type="area"/>
  <union into="_">
    <query into="_" type="node">
      <has-kv k="amenity" modv="" v="hospital"/>
      <has-kv k="emergency" modv="" v="yes"/>
      <area-query from="searchArea" into="_" ref=""/>
    </query>
  </union>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" limit="" mode="body" n="" order="id" s="" w=""/>
  <recurse from="_" into="_" type="down"/>
  <print e="" from="_" geometry="skeleton" limit="" mode="skeleton" n="" order="quadtile" s="" w=""/>
</osm-script>
```

Note that I've changed the output format from `json` to `xml` .....

Then I've modified my `wget` command

```
wget -e use_proxy=yes -e http_proxy=<proxy>:port> --post-file=ps_from_OSM.txt http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter --output-document=ps_From_OSM.osm
```

Then convert in ESRI shapefile ...

```
ogr2ogr -nlt POINT -skipfailures TMP_DIR ps_From_OSM.osm
```

NOTE: this command create a DIRECTORY and in this directory there are the shapefiles